# Do leaked potassium hydroxide from AA alkaline batteries, eventually become potassium bicarbonate?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I understand that liquid leaked from AA alkaline batteries is an aqueous solution of potassium hydroxide (which is highly alkaline). It becomes potassium carbonate (which is less alkaline than potassium hydroxide but still relatively alkaline) once exposed to air (or, more precisely, to carbon dioxide).

I also understand that potassium carbonate becomes potassium bicarbonate (which is mildly alkaline) once exposed to air (or, more precisely, to carbon dioxide).

I have two questions:

1. Then, does it mean that an aqueous solution of potassium hydroxide from AA alkaline batteries will first become potassium carbonate and then potassium bicarbonate, if they are left untouched and exposed to air (as in normal life)?
2. If potassium carbonate, which was created by exposing potassium hydroxide to carbon dioxide, were exposed to water, would it become an aqueous solution of potassium hydroxide (which would perhaps be more dilute than the original)? Similarly, if potassium bicarbonate were exposed to water, would it become an aqueous solution of potassium hydroxide (which would perhaps be even more dilute than the original)?

I am asking this question, basically to know if it is safer to wait longer (i.e., for potassium hydroxide to become potassium bicarbonate) before I clean leaked liquid from AA alkaline batteries.

I would appreciate your inputs. Apologies if the questions sound nonsensical; chemistry is not my strong area.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario has 2 paths:

If the diffusion driven reaction with aerial carbon dioxide is faster than solution drying up, it follows the full reaction scheme:

$$\ce{KOH(aq) ->[+ CO2] K2CO3(aq) ->[+ CO2] KHCO3(aq)}$$

But the above path is not very probable for AA cell leakage cases, as the solution usually dries up before the formation of bicarbonate is completed. It then stops at achieved progress of formation of potassium carbonate/bicarbonate:

$$\ce{KOH(aq,s) ->[+ CO2][- H2O] K2CO3(s) (+ KHCO3(s))},$$

as dry potassium carbonate does not react with carbon dioxide any more.

---

In solution, $\ce{K2CO3(aq)}$ partially hydrolyzes, forming minor concentration of $\ce{KOH}$.

$$\ce{CO3^2-(aq) + H2O(l) <=> HCO3- + OH-(aq)}$$

$\ce{KHCO3(aq)}$ hydrolyzes too, but negligibly, forming minor concentration of $\ce{KHCO3}$ and negligible traces of $\ce{KOH(aq)}$.

$$\ce{HCO3-(aq) + H2O(l) <<=> H2O(l) + CO2(aq) + OH-(aq)}$$

---

It is always good to neutralize strong acids/bases by weak bases/acids, not strong ones. Otherwise we figuratively "release a wedge by another wedge". It is good practice to keep handy in a lab neutralization solutions of 2 % acetic acid (at home use diluted vinegar) and 2 % sodium bicarbonate (baking soda).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Re: your first answer, which is generally more common: potassium hydroxide becoming potassium bicarbonate before the solution drying up, or stopping at potassium carbonate? It might depend on the amount of liquid and the external environment, but is it possible to find a general theory that explains the relative speed of drying up and the process to potassium bicarbonate? (In my layperson view, an environment that fastens drying up seems also to fasten the exposure of potassium hydroxide solution to the air, so the relationship seems not inverse)

Comment: I guess you may overthink it. Just wipe the leakage or dried up residue by clothes or paper napkin/tissue, soaked by diluted vinegar and then water. // General theory says it depends on particular scenario, geometry and conditions. E.g. higher temperature means faster evaporation but slower CO2 dissolution, supporting the "dry path".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Your question $1$ is correctly treated. Exposed to air, potassium hydroxide solutions become slowly potassium carbonate solutions, then potassium bicarbonate solutions. But this operation is not reversible. In question $2$, potassium carbonate solutions or potassium bicarbonate solutions will never spontaneously be transformed into potassium hydroxide solutions, diluted or not. And yes, in next paragraph, it is better to wait a long time before throwing away the liquid coming out of an AAA alkaline battery. Of course, it is much quicker if this alkaline solution is neutralized by any acidic solution (like hydrochloric acid) before getting rid of it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but thank you for the answer!